# Redisson quorum configuration

Tags: redis, redisson, quorum

Can we setup quorum size while acquiring the lock in redisson? We wanted to make sure redis master node fail-over condition does not result in dirty read/writes.
Ref: https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/2669